# Changing duration of multiple After Effects layers at once

Tags: after-effects, presentation

Can I set duration of multiple After Effects (freezed frame) layers to a fixes value (e.g. 4 seconds each) at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Select all of the layers.  Move the time cursor to where you want the layers duration to end.  Press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>. This will extend your layer to that position (if it is able to be extended).

Pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> would adjust the in point

Pressing Press <kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>]</kbd> on their own would move the in or out point of the layer to your current time position.

Comment: also if you're shifting layers around https://aescripts.com/pt_shiftlayers/ is v useful

Comment: Those freezed frame layers are distributed around my composition between non-freezed layers which I dont want to modify.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I aligned all the freezed frame layers to the cursor using [, moved the cursor 4 seconds forward and used alt+[ to apply a single out point to all (and finally sequnced them using animation>keyframe assistant).